# Python Django Forms how to create object using multiple sub-objects?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create form that will allow me to create Meal object using multiple MealItem sub-objects which also have parameter of quantity, however up to this point I was able to create form and view combination that will allow me either to pick only one sub-object with one quantity

Models:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=meal_image_upload_to, blank=True, null=True)

    def calculate_total_macros(self):
        total_kcal = 0
        total_carbohydrates = 0
        total_fats = 0
        total_proteins = 0
        total_glycemic_load = 0
        total_glycemic_index = 0
        total_weight = 0
        weighted_glycemic_index = 0

        meal_items = self.mealitem_set.all()
        for meal_item in meal_items:
            quantity = meal_item.quantity
            food_item = meal_item.food_item
            total_weight += quantity

            total_kcal += food_item.kcal * quantity/100 #food items have nutrition facts per 100g
            total_carbohydrates += food_item.carbohydrates * quantity/100
            total_fats += food_item.fats * quantity/100
            total_proteins += food_item.proteins * quantity/100
            total_glycemic_load += food_item.glycemic_load * quantity/100
            total_glycemic_index += food_item.glycemic_index
            weighted_glycemic_index += food_item.glycemic_index * quantity

        if total_weight != 0:
            total_kcal_per_100g = round((total_kcal / total_weight) * 100, 2)
            total_carbohydrates_per_100g = round((total_carbohydrates / total_weight) * 100, 2)
            total_fats_per_100g = round((total_fats / total_weight) * 100, 2)
            total_proteins_per_100g = round((total_proteins / total_weight) * 100, 2)
            total_glycemic_load_per_100g = round((total_glycemic_load / total_weight) * 100, 2)
        else:
            total_kcal_per_100g = 0
            total_carbohydrates_per_100g = 0
            total_fats_per_100g = 0
            total_proteins_per_100g = 0
            total_glycemic_load_per_100g = 0

        average_glycemic_index = round(weighted_glycemic_index / total_weight, 2)

        return {
            'total_kcal': total_kcal,
            'total_carbohydrates': total_carbohydrates,
            'total_fats': total_fats,
            'total_proteins': total_proteins,
            'total_glycemic_load': total_glycemic_load,
            'total_kcal_per_100g': total_kcal_per_100g,
            'total_carbohydrates_per_100g': total_carbohydrates_per_100g,
            'total_fats_per_100g': total_fats_per_100g,
            'total_proteins_per_100g': total_proteins_per_100g,
            'total_glycemic_load_per_100g': total_glycemic_load_per_100g,
            'average_glycemic_index': average_glycemic_index
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MealItem(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_item = models.ForeignKey(FoodItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.food_item.name} - {self.meal.name}"
```

forms:

```
class MealItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MealItem
        fields = ['food_item', 'quantity']


MealItemFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Meal, MealItem, form=MealItemForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)


class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = ['name', 'image']

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MealForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def save(self, commit=True):
        meal = super(MealForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.user:
            meal.user = self.user
        if commit:
            meal.save()
        return meal
```

views:

```
def add_meal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MealForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = MealItemFormSet(request.POST, instance=Meal())

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            meal = form.save()
            formset.instance = meal
            formset.save()

            return redirect('meal_list')

    else:
        form = MealForm(user=request.user)
        formset = MealItemFormSet(instance=Meal())

    return render(request, 'add_meal.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Meal">
</form>
```

I've tried working with prefixes or changing the forms however all I've managed was to get to the point where I could've picked multiple MealItem sub-objects but couldn't choose individual quantity for each one of them